timed out (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS while connecting to Amazon DocumentDB
We have an Amazon DocumentDB. I need to write a script which could connect to that Db and do some operations on the collections(like- insert, createIndex etc). I have intermediate knowledge in python but I am working with Amazon DocumentDB for first time. I was following this AWS documentation
Here is my script to connect to the DB
def connect_to_mongodb_ssl(host, port, username, password, ca_file):
    try:
        # MongoDB URI
        uri = f'mongodb://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/?tls=true&tlsCAFile=global-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false'
        
        # Connect to MongoDB
        client = MongoClient(uri, serverSelectionTimeoutMS=60000)
        
        # Check if connection was successful
        if client is not None:
            print("Connected to MongoDB successfully!")
            return client
        else:
            print("Failed to connect to MongoDB.")
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred while connecting to MongoDB:", e)
        return None

Here is my main function
def main():
    try:  
       ...
        download_certificate()
        client = connect_to_mongodb_ssl(host, port, username, password, 'global-bundle.pem')  
        # Access a database and collection
        db = client.database_document_db
        collection = db.collection_1
        collection.insert_one({'hello':'Amazon DocumentDB'})
        ##Find the document that was previously written
        x = collection.find_one({'hello':'Amazon DocumentDB'})
        ##Print the result to the screen
        print(x)
        client.close()
   
    except Exception as e:
        print("\nERROR: Error in the DODSD Usage Tool execution.")
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    else:
        return
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Now while I am executing this script, it is able to create mongoClient. But when it is trying to execute any command using that client, I am getting SocketException with Timeout. I increased the timeout time also. But none worked so far. Here is the logs

Certificate downloaded successfully to 'global-bundle.pem' Connected
to MongoDB successfully!
ERROR: Error in the DODSD Usage Tool execution.
ERROR:root:dods-dev-documentdb.cluster-cvrugh24j6d8.us-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017:
timed out (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms,
connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms), Timeout: 60.0s, Topology Description:
<TopologyDescription id: 6644c22384feb584e20bcc03, topology_type:
ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription
('dods-dev-documentdb.cluster-cvrugh24j6d8.us-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com',
27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None,
error=NetworkTimeout('dods-dev-documentdb.cluster-cvrugh24j6d8.us-west-2.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017:
timed out (configured timeouts: socketTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms,
connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)')>]>

Can anyone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong here?
